# How can I get an MD5 checksum of an image at a specific URL in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, md5

How can I get an MD5 checksum of an image at a specific URL in JavaScript? I would like to write a function like this:

> var checksum = imageMD5Checksum('http://link.to/image.jpg');

which would return an MD5 checksum string of the image (e.g. 'f0bf4ed11b011217bdb46f8d7b08dea2').

Comment: You can use `XMLHttpRequest` to get the image data, then use a JavaScript hashing library to generate a MD5 of the image data.

Comment: I keep getting the following error in Chrome: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` I know I could resolve the issue by modifying the response header, but I would like my function to work with any external image links. Any ideas?

Comment: i for one would NOT like your function to work on any site's images. follow the rules or get a server.

Comment: Not javascript, but hopefully useful to someone who lands on this page: `curl 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png' | md5sum`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting up a proxy server for image downloads. Thanks a lot for pointers!